# How to read app.config from another assembly?

Tags: c#, app-config

I have two projects:

- Console project (Test.exe)
- Class Library project (Test.Data.dll)

My Class Library project contains an `app.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBNews.csdl|res://*/DBNews.ssdl|res://*/DBNews.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;{0}&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

From the Console project I want to access the settings from the Class Library, so I've tried:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Test.Data.dll");
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[0].Name; // LocalSqlServer
// seems to be the wrong assembly.
```

And:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Test.Data.dll.config");
// invalid exePath
```

How can I access the DLL's `app.config` ?

Comment: The correct answer ist given here. It works
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545/get-the-app-config-of-another-exe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DLL doesn't have its own app.config at runtime. The app.config is only there for the Entity Framework designer.

During execution, the DLL will try to read the values from the Application's app.config file. For Entity Framework connections, that means you have to copy the connection information into the Application's app.config.

Answer (score 7):

.NET will only load at most one App.config file for an executing assembly. If your satellite assemblies have App.config files, they will not be parsed by the executing assembly.

In order to get the settings from the satellite assembly's App.config you must move (copy) those settings into your executing assembly's App.config.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this. Assuming your assembly with the connection string in it's .config file is a reference in your project and so exists along side the executing assembly.

```
String AssemblyName = "MyAssemblyWithConfig.dll";
String appConfigPath = new FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\" + AssemblyName + ".config";
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", appConfigPath);
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestEntities"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string value = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "yourassembly.dll"))?.AppSettings.Settings["yourAppconfigKey"].Value ?? "";
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?